# How to fix SVG overlapping polygons

Tags: svg

I'm working on a SVG image, but i have a problem with overlapping polygons.

[image: Background polygon's color is shown on the right of the gray polygon]

Does anyone know how I could fix this without having to change my polygons ? (I'd like to hide the brown line on the right)

Comment: Please post an [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the grey polygon is on top of the brown one (I can only guess because you haven't posted the SVG), then you have several options:

1. Make the brown shape smaller)
2. Make the grey one larger
3. Give the grey shape a small (eg. 1px) grey `stroke` to hide the antialiasing of the brown edge..

Comment: Tested with the stroke, it's exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks !